# Can I get parameters back from a parameterized Jenkins build job?

Tags: jenkins

I have defined my Jenkins jobs in this way:

```
"Integration tests" Job >> "Deploy" Job
```

Whenever "Integration tests" job is fired it triggers a parameterized "Deploy" Job.
Let's say I pass parameters like: USER_ID to uniquely identify my application.

Now the "Deploy" job uses this USER_ID parameter, creates and deploys the application.
A typical application URL gets created like:

```
http://myApplication-userA (assume USER_ID has 'userA' value)
```

What I want is this URL value back to my "Integration Tests" job. I have used Parameterized plugin to pass the value to further job, but is there a way where I can get back a value from by "Deploy" Job?

Although, I know the logic of creating unique applications is within "Deploy" job and can very well predict the URL. But a cleaner solution would be to get back the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen anything like this, short of storing temporary files in a mutually accessible location to both jobs.

What you can do is read the console output of `Deploy` job and parse it for whatever output you are looking for. Obviously, the `Deploy` job would have to print to console the information you are looking for.

You can read the console output of the `Deploy` job with `http://[HUDSON]/job/[Deploy_JOB_NAME]/lastBuild/logText/progressiveText?start=0`

Read more about it by adding `/api` to the end of any job's URL

Comment: I will try the console output parsing and also look at the /api. Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I have not tried yet is to add a new environment variable [1]. The good part about it is that environment variables' global shared state seems to be accepted as a must-have and is quite ubiquitous.

How did you end up solving it? Anne

1.[] https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Comment: I ended up using temporary files in shared location: Integration Job creates  a temporary file with unique name. It could send that file name or uniqueness to next job(Deploy job here). After the deploy job finishes updates the file with the status.